# Playwright JS testing password input with masked smaller inputs (for each sign)

Tags: javascript, validation, testing, input, playwright

If a locator below is checked with 'isEnabled' option and the input is blank and focusable, the  sign is typed correctly :
const maskAvailable = await page.isEnabled(`input#mask-${maskNr}.form-control`);

But the problem begins with another field that is inactive and greyed out - playwright doesn't make any action, ends up with error.

In addition 'isVisible' option works fine for inactive fields, but it doesn't with active ones.

Code below :

const signs = ['x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%'];
var maskNr;

```
for (maskNr = 1; maskNr < 14; maskNr++) {
    const maskAvailable = await page.isEnabled(`input#mask-${maskNr}.form-control`);

    if (maskAvailable) {
        const sign = signs[maskNr-1];
        await page.type(`input#mask-${maskNr}.form-control`, sign, { delay: 100 });
    }
}
```

In addition, if the field is active it has a locator/selector is "input#mark-nr.form-control", if it's not, there'ss only "div.some-password-container__password--field.some-empty.js-field::before".

Working out with for loop as above, also with checking if the selector has a unique class. But with no success.

Comment: This could use a [mcve].